# Use parameterized dataset for DataFlow

Tags: azure, csv, dataset, azure-data-factory

I am trying to use a global parameterized dataset as a source and as a sink in my data flow inside my data factory. But the test connection fails in my data flow. It only works if I don't use parameters. It works if I change the 'item().name' to the file's name.

[My dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj5qk.png)

[The parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOVI6.png)

[The dataflow error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjbPU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters are valid only in their scope i.e. you cannot use a pipeline parameter in the dataset parameter default value directly. You can only provide static values in the default field for dataset parameters.

**Checkout the same error:**

[image]

**Workaround:**

In your scenario, since you have a **parameterized dataset** in dataflow, when using `dataflow` activity in Pipeline, you will be prompted to provide values to those properties. Here you can mention that Global Parameter.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: My pleasure..  