# ADF - Iterate through blob container containing JSON files, partition and push to various SQL tables

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have a blob storage container in Azure Data Factory that contains many JSON files. Each of these JSON files contain data from an API. The data needs to be split into ~30 tables in my azure DWH.

[ADF Processhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nJQy.png)

I am hoping someone can provide some clarity on the best way to achieve this (I am new to the field of Data Engineering and trying to develop my skills through projects).

At present, I have written 1 stored procedure which contains code to extract data and insert data into 1 of the 30 tables. Is this the right approach? And if so, could you please advise how best to design my pipeline?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the number of JSON files from Blob and tables are same?

Comment: No, in the end I will have thousands of JSON files. Within each 1 JSON files is data to populate ~30 tables.

Comment: So, you want to combine all JSON files and then copy the result file into 30 SQL tables with equal amount of data, right? or every JSON should copy its data to 30 SQL tables?

Comment: Well this is where I have a knowledge gap. Is there a best approach here or does it not really matter? I don't mind whether I combine all files, push to separate blob area, and apply the stored procedures that way (and remove the combined data file when completed) or apply some sort of iterator over each file separately.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the you also have 30 folders in the containers and eachdata from each folder will land up in a table or may be the file are named in a such a way that you can dereive which table it lands on . Please read about Get meta data activity and it should give an idea as to how to get the filename/folder name : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity

Once you have that I think you should read about paramterizing a dataset : [Use parameterized dataset for DataFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70315146/use-parameterized-dataset-for-dataflow)  and this also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9XSJih4k-l8

Comment: So I have one blob container where I dump all JSON files each time I pull the latest json files (there are many files). I was thinking about using a control table to specify the stored procedure and output table name and maybe using a lookup somewhere to derive what stored procedure to run and where to push the output, any thoughts?

Comment: if you have a lot of files, please put some thoughts on how to get the latest file. Get metadata will iterate though all the files in the container/Folder to get the most recent file. Also the max size return has a cap of 4 MB .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity#supported-capabilities